# Macrodroid: how to check the level of brightness with "if-clause" (conditions/loops)

Tags: screen-brightness, macrodroid

I would like to increase the brightness of the device from 0 percent to 100 percent if some trigger occurs (e.g. at volume button's long press).

I have created a macro as follows but it does not work: when I press volume button's long press the brightness does not change from 0 to 100.

More information:

- I am able to set the brightness to 100% outside of "if-clause" in Macrodroid.
- "Volume Down -Long press" works without problem as a trigger with other macros (if any).
- I have tested with or without option, "Alternative Android 9+ mode".
- The android version of the device is 12.
- I also tested with the option "Brightness Less than 1%" in "if-clause" without success.

[image]

Comment: I think the macro is not working because the brightness is never equals to 0%. Are you able to set it to 0%? You should try using "Less than" or "Greater than" if the phone never reaches 0%.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thank you for your comment. It seems that macrodroid is not sensible to small values.

Comment: Many (possibly most/all) phones don't allow the brightness to reach 0%. You need to find a small value, try maybe if brightness < 30%, then set it to 100%.